# Toilet bubbles and gurgles after capping vent stack

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain-waste-vent

We had a bad wax ring on the toilet so we replaced that, then we decided to replace the toilet with a newer model. Now the toilet doesn't flush right--sometimes we have to flush it a couples of times for things to go down.

We thought it might be a clog so we had a plumber company clean the lines out there was nothing blocking it. They suggested that the vent stack might be clogged so we flushed it out with water and capped the vent pipe. However, the toilet is still acting up with bubbling and gurgling sounds and we can't figure out whats going on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sanity check: What do you mean by "cap the vent pipe"? presumably something which still lets air through so it serves its purpose, right?

Answer (score 2):

The bubbling and gurgling sounds from the toilet(s) is an indication of poor venting or a plugging issue. Also, you should **not** have to "flush it a couples off times for things to go down" unless there is a special circumstance (like too much paper... or something).

Call a reputable licensed plumber and have your entire system assessed, including camera inspection. Then pay appropriately to have the root cause addressed.